# Canadian Mathematical Olympiad 2007 Question 5

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let the incircle of triangle $ABC$ touch sides $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$ at $D$, $E$ and $F$, respectively. Let $Γ$,$Γ_1$,$Γ_2$ and $Γ_3$ denote the
circumcircles of triangle $ABC$, $AEF$, $BDF$ and $CDE$ respectively. Let $Γ$ and $Γ_1$ intersect at $A$ and $P$, $Γ$ and $Γ_2$ intersect
at $B$ and $Q$, and $Γ$ and $Γ_3$ intersect at $C$ and $R$.

Prove that $PEDQ$ is cyclic.

[image]

Comment: What did you try ? What are your thoughts ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Angle chase doesn't seem to work...

Comment: This question, oddly, is rather similar to a question that has been asked almost at the same time : (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2225131)

Comment: @JeanMarie: this problem has a quite simple solution through circle inversion; I am not so sure the same applies to the other question.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution using purely angle chasing (though it does require quite a bit of ingenuity and playing around with angles).

Let $I$ be the incenter. It is easy to see $I\in\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2,\Gamma_3$. Then:

\begin{align*}
\angle QPE = \angle QPA-\angle APE \\=\angle QPA-\angle AIE\\=180^{\circ}-\angle QBA-90^{\circ}+\frac{1}{2}\angle A\\=180^{\circ}-\angle QBA-\frac{1}{2}\angle B-\frac{1}{2}\angle C\\=180^{\circ}-\angle QBA-\angle ABI-\angle IDE\\=180^{\circ}-\angle QBI-\angle IDE\\=180^{\circ}-\angle QDI-\angle IDE\\=180^{\circ}-\angle QDE
\end{align*}

(Here I use the notation $\angle A$ to denote $\angle BAC$, etc.)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Very interesting problem. I will perform a slight change of notation for simplicity. Let $ABC$ be the starting triangle, $I$ its incenter, $I_A, I_B, I_C$ the projections of the incenter on the sides of $ABC$. The key idea is to perform a circular inversion with respect to the incircle of $ABC$. It is straightforward to check that the circumcircles of $II_A I_B$ and so on go into $I_A I_B$ and so on. Additionally, the sides of $ABC$ go into the circles $\Theta_A,\Theta_B,\Theta_C$ with diameters $II_A,II_B,II_C$. These circles meet at $I$ and at the midpoints of the sides of $I_A I_B I_C$. By [Johnson's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JohnsonsTheorem.html) the inverse $\Xi$ of the circumcircle of $ABC$ has the same diameter of $\Theta_A$. In particular $\Xi$ is the nine point circle of $I_A I_B I_C$ and the other intersections of $\Xi$ with the side lengths of $I_A I_B I_C$ are given by the feet of the altitudes of $I_A I_B I_C$.

The problem now boils down to a trivial one: i.e. to show that in a triangle $ABC$ the vertices $B,C$ and the feet of the altitudes $H_B,H_C$ are concyclic.

[image]

Comment: [+1] Interesting problem and solution ! Indeed the other problem is not of the same nature...

Comment: @JeanMarie: many thanks. It looks like the other question can be tackled by exploiting some interesting properties of the symmedian point.